# Android / Eclipse / Emulator / WAMP: Error 503 and timeouts

Tags: eclipse, json, apache, android-emulator, wamp

I am trying to request JSON data from a PHP script in my Android app.

The whole thing works well when I'm directly connecting my mobile phone and directly access the "real" Internet webserver. However, it doesn't work at all using the emulator and localhost (WAMP installation). Running the script directly on the local webserver, again, gives me the expected results- only if I am calling it on the same machine using the emulator, the troubles begin.

Here are the combinations I have tried so far (the scripts are located in the subdirectory "zz" of the root):

```
private static String url_all_venues = "http://10.0.2.2/zz/pullvenuesjson.php";
```

or

```
private static String url_all_venues = "http://10.0.2.2:80/zz/pullvenuesjson.php";
```

leads to the following exception: E/JSON Parser(657): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

When I'm trying the following:

```
private static String url_all_venues = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/zz/pullvenuesjson.php";
```

the code runs 'forever' and I'm getting a timeout error after about 5 minutes.

Any idea how to fix that so I can also test my app on my local webserver / the emulator? Most probably the problem is in my local Apache configuration, but then, I'm not sure…

**EDIT:**

Here is some of the code that seems to trigger the error:

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

"url" is the one mentioned above. As mentioned in my comment below, it looks as if the problem comes from the local WAMP webserver not responding appropriately, since the code works fine when I'm directly accessing the "real" server via the Internet (i.o.w, do nothing else than changing the URL to the Internet address of the php script). The odd thing is that the script also works fine when I run it locally, but NOT through the emulator.

Comment: The actual error message is "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". So it seems the local webserver returns some error document, and I bet it's Error 503.
I have posted some of the code below.

Comment: Maybe problem with MIME type of server's result?

Comment: Could you add some server side code too?

Comment: I finally figured it out! I logged the transferred data using **Log.d(..)** and found out that the username/password combination was not valid as I didn't check for the localhost condition...
The script and app retrieves the data just fine now on both, localhost and the web. Thanks for your inquiries which helped me to get down to the root of the error!

Comment: Just add that as your answer, and you will be able to close out this question.

Comment: @richey Please add your solution as an answer to this question and the accept it, so you question does not show up as unanswered anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I logged the transferred data using Log.d(..) and found out that the username/password combination was not valid as I didn't check for the localhost condition... The script and app retrieves the data just fine now on both, localhost and the web. Thanks for your inquiries which helped me to get down to the root of the error!

[Answered myself in order to avoid the Q showing up as unanswered]